How to copy specific mip map level from a source texture to a specific mip map level in a destination texture?
I'm merging many 2D textures into an Array Texture in WebGL2 (three.js) for rendering models with multi draw. These individual textures change frequently and are using mipmaps. Because it's not possible to generate mipmaps for just an individual layer in an Array Texture I would like to generate mipmaps for a 2d target and then copy the entire mipmap chain into a specific layer for the given texture.
However, looking through the WebGL API it seems like it's not possible to bind a specific mipmap level from a texture created with texStorage2D and copy it into a specific mipmap level for a layer in the 3d texture. This is happening in three.js but here are the rough copy commands being done:
_gl.pixelStorei( _gl.UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, image.width );
_gl.pixelStorei( _gl.UNPACK_IMAGE_HEIGHT, image.height );
_gl.pixelStorei( _gl.UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, minX );
_gl.pixelStorei( _gl.UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, minY );

gl.bindTexture( _gl.TEXTURE_2D, srcTextureHandle, _gl.TEXTURE0 );
gl.copyTexSubImage3D( _gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level, dstX, dstY, dstZ, minX, minY, width, height );

I see it's possible to set the target mip level in the arguments of copyTexSubImage3D but I don't see a way to specify the mip level to copy for the bound texture.
I see there's a glCopyImageSubData function in the OpenGLES3.2 spec that allows for specifying source and target mip levels but there's no equivalent available in browsers. Is this possible in WebGL2?
